# Complex plane and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

What differences -if any- are there between the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I am taking multi variable analysis now and I was wondering what possible changes there might be from the Analysis of two dimensions vs Complex Analysis.

A short summary of the differences would suffice.

Comment: Complex analysis is concerned with complex-differentiable functions (mostly), these are much more regular than a real-differentiable function of two real variables usually is.

Comment: Enormous. Hint: do you have a product in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: The big difference is differentiability, which looks similar to differentiating functions $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, but ends up becoming substantially different because unlike in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have a well defined product operation which induces a multiplicative inverse for all non-zero elements. This changes the notion of differentiability -- actually, it induces a more restrictive definition -- which leads to classes of functions that have very interesting properties. See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/444491/31475

Answer (score 1):

Topologicaly they are the same, but algebraicaly not. Elements in $R^2$ and $C$ have different rules. Example in $R^2$ we have $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)=x_1x_2+y_1y_2$, but in $C$ we have $(x_1+y_1i)(x_2+y_2i)=x_1x_2-y_1y_2+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)i$ or $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2,)=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is no standard product, although the one you just defined is one of many possible products.

Comment: I disagree with you, because the 'natural' comparation of $C$ and $R^2$ can be made for the Euclidean (orthonormal) $R^2$. But still if you think that it can be for 'any' $R^2$, than we can put the general form of dot product: $xy=|x||y|cos\phi$ where $x,y \in R^2$ and $\phi$ is the angle between the coordinative vectors. So $xy=|x||y|cos\phi$ is still different from the product in $C$.

Comment: The dot product maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Direct products from $R^2$ to $R^2$ in general come with a natural dot product: $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2,y_1y_2)$.

Comment: I hardly see that as a dot product, but it is, as you said, a direct product. Which is one possible natural product on $\mathbb{R}^2$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general. But it has little to do with the "Euclidean" characteristics of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or those of $\mathbb{C}$. In fact, the direct product fails to satisfy the one Euclidean property we really care about: $\| u\otimes v\| = \|u\|\|v\|$, viz., $$\|u\otimes v\| = \sqrt{(x_1 x_2)^2+(y_1y_2)^2} \neq \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2} = \|u\|\|v\|.$$

Comment: You are right.  
But still that what you say doesn't deny my claim that $R^2$ and $C$ differ algebraically.

Comment: It's true, they do differ algebraically. I don't dispute that. They differ because $\mathbb{C}$ has a standard product, where $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not. We could define $\mathbb{R}^2$'s product as $\mathbb{C}$'s product and have a complete isomorphism, though.

Comment: Bthw you've helped me to understand how we define products from $R^n$ to $R^m$. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Think about this. In the definition of derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$: $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h},$$ what doesn't make sense if $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ but does if $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C$?