# Is it appropriate to apply Euclidean Distance to Complex Numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

Would complex numbers be considered as part of Euclidean Space? Would this measurement give an accurate result? If not, what would be a more appropriate distance measurement/similarity measure with respect to complex numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use the Euclidean idea of distance between two complex numbers
$$
|z_2 - z_1| = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}
$$

However, the complex plane contains more algebraic structure than plain euclidean space $R^2$ so calling complex numbers "part of the euclidean space" is not quite accurate. [Here is a link to another question with a discussion of the differences between the two.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444475/whats-the-difference-between-mathbbr2-and-the-complex-plane)

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean distance is exactly what we get when we consider the modulus of a complex number: $$|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

so it makes complete sense to use Euclidian distance, and this is in some sense the most natural distance to choose, since $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.