# Are complex numbers and $(x,y)$ coordinates two sides of the same coin?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm learning that imaginary numbers are just a way of representing a rotation. So, are imaginary numbers and multiple variable numbers $(x,y,z,...)$ just two different tools for representing numbers in multiple dimensions? Or are imaginary numbers still part of the same tool where $(x,y)$ represent points on a plane, and I'm misunderstanding their utility?

So it doesn't make sense to talk about calculus with complex numbers, since calculus is a tool to deal with functions of multiple variables?

Comment: I actually like this question, I've been asking it to my self many times. However I will let the intelligent people answer :)

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444475/whats-the-difference-between-mathbbr2-and-the-complex-plane) may be of interest.

Comment: $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ is in a sense natural, but $(a,b)\times (c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ is a specific property of complex numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> calculus is a tool to deal with functions of multiple variables

You probably mean "multivariate calculus", because ordinary calculus deals with single variables just fine.

---

There are several valid ways of looking at the complex numbers. One of the ways is to se $\mathbb C$ (the set of all complex numbers) as a vector space over $\mathbb R$. In that case, yes, you can look at $\mathbb C$ the same way as $\mathbb R^2$.

But this view misses two important points, one "positive" one not:

- **Plus** : $\mathbb C$ is **much more** than just $\mathbb R^2$. Because you can multiply and divide complex numbers in a particular way, the complex numbers form what is called a *field*, making them very useful for all sorts of things. Furthermore, in complex numbers, you can define a complex derivative of a function similar to that in the real numbers, but having much nicer properties (see *[holomorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function)*). This, along with some other nice properties, is the reason that there is an entire subfield of analysis entirely devoted to functions of complex variables (*[complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis)*) So, you could say that $\mathbb C$ is a very rich version of $\mathbb R^2$.
- **Minus**: This is only true for $2$. You cannot "enrich" $\mathbb R^3$ (this is a very complicated mathematical result called the *[Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras))*) in a similar way, and you can only partially do it with $\mathbb R^4$ (see [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.