# Euclidean distance for Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I was searching around for whether or not I could use the Euclidean distance with complex numbers because it seems to make sense but I was struggling to really know. I found someone say that it is true that we can use the euclidean distance because $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that just doesn't seem right to me at all, however when I research it I keep finding conflicting information.

I think I'm misunderstanding what isomorphic means here, because it seems to me that group operations aren't preserved between the two.

Comment: Say *what's* true?  This question is very unclear the way it's phrased.

Comment: The claim was that "It's true that you can use Eucliean Distance for Complex Numbers" and justified by "$\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$"

Comment: Yes, it's true.  The complex number $a + bi$ corresponds to the point $(a,b)$ in the $xy$-plane.  So to find the Euclidean distance between $z = a + bi$ and $w = x + yi$, just find the Euclidean distance between the points $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorhpic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}$, so your "hunch" is misguided. The fact that $\not\exists n\in\mathbb{R}:n^2=-1$ doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: What you can't do is compare two imaginary numbers in the same way that you can compare real numbers, e.g., $1 < 2$.  There's no corresponding notion of "order" for imaginary numbers.

Comment: So, then, is $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and how can I know that?

Comment: I gave you the isomorphism above without calling it an isomorphism.  The point $a+bi$ in $\Bbb C$ corresponds to the point $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking at $|z_1-z_2|^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$ where $z_k=x_k+ i y_k$ for $k=1,2$.

Comment: My issue here is that maybe I misunderstand or misremember Isomorphism as preserving group operations?

Comment: @Blake See [What's the difference between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444475).

Comment: It is only isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ if you define a suitable multiplication on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: However, you can use the distance $d(z,w) = |z-w|$ regardless of any isomorphism.

Comment: The first secret is the shortcut $z \overline{z} =  \overline{z} z = |z|^2$ which boils down "by accident" to as if it was meant for the euclidean metric over $\mathbb{R^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Isomorphic here is regarding $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ as both being $2$ dimensional vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Vector spaces after all. Or before..

Let's see you get a non zero real number from a linear combination of smiley faces and frowny faces. :D

Answer (score 1):

The function

$$f(a+ib)=(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$$

is a (field) isomorphism, where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is usual group with pointwise addition and multiplication is defined as it should be:

$$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$$

This gives you $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)+f(z_2)$ and $f(z_1z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$.

Since once can define Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ then you can traslate this definition back to $\mathbb{C}$ via isomorphism.